# How to write JSON mixed mode data?

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I want to write a combination of dictionary and data array.

My data looks like this

The function I use is

```
  func writeJSONdata()
  {
    var error: NSError?
    var filename:String = "testWrite.json"
    var dict:NSMutableDictionary = ["3Dmodel":"Model_Student_v3",
"3Ddata":"testdata file",
"3DColors":"color file name"]

    var myArray:[Float] = [1.0,-0.13131,12.0]

    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
      NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
      NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
      true
    )
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String
    let filePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

    if let outputJSON = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePath, append: false)
    {
      outputJSON.open()
      NSJSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(dict, toStream: outputJSON, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: &error)
      NSJSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(myArray, toStream: outputJSON, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: &error)
      outputJSON.close()
    }
  }
```

Of course the JSON is not valid as there is no name to attach to the array.

```
> {
>     "3Dmodel": "Model_Student_v3",
>     "3DColors": "color file name",
>     "3Ddata": "testdata file" }[
>     1,
>     -0.13131,
>     12 ]
```

It should look like

```
{
    "3Dmodel": "Model_Student_v3",
    "3DColors": "color file name",
    "3Ddata": "testdata file",
    "data": [
        1,
        -0.13131,
        12
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dict ["data"] = myArray and then write dict.

Comment: Thanks that work but it looks ugly, why doesn't is append the array to the end? instead of the middle?    {
    "3DColors": "color file name",
    "data": [
        1,
        -0.13131,
        12
    ],
    "3Dmodel": "Model_Student_v3",
    "3Ddata": "testdata file"
}